# avoid multiple click while clicking

Tags: angular

```
<li  *ngFor="let deletedTask of deletedTasks; let i=index">
 <i (click)= "getItem(deletedTask, i)"></i>
</li>


getItem(item, index){

 this.service.getTask(reqMap).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((resp: any) => {})
}
```

I am trying to fetch data only one time even user clicks multiple time but this does not work
How to use take operator  or debounce operator for this . I have tried disabling button with boolean values and binding [ngClass] to disable pointer but the use case is such as i am restoring the value so if multiple value has been deleted and I am trying to restore then it gives me option to restore value only once, rest deleted value cannot be restored .

Comment: the easy way will be to add a parent function with a flag that checks if the call finish before proceed to the call which will block the multiple calls. The better option is to bound it to observable that does it automatically with the subscription to the call.

Comment: as @dAxx_ mentioned, it will be easier to just have a variable that you toggle once you start your call, then at the end you can toggle it off. you can mark your button as disabled using that variable, as well as you can return early from handler function

Comment: Do you want to disable the getItem function only when the API is still running or do you want to make it so that it can be clicked only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UX wise I don't know why your attaching a click listener to an a list item but maybe you have this sorted out with some css otherwise an `<a>` link or button would be more clear what it does. What is `reqMap` and why you never use it? Why do you have `index` on `*ngFor` but never use it?

Anyway, lets hold pending requests (as the delete obj's) in array and clear them once request is done. As redundancy we clear the item from pending array after 10 seconds in case a requests fails (we don't want to keep the get button disabled forever).

```html
<li *ngFor="let deletedTask of deletedTasks">
  <i>{{ deletedTask }}</i>
  <button (click)="getItem(deletedTask)" [disabled]="pending.includes(deletedTask)">getItem</button>
</li>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  deletedTasks = ['Milk', 'Bread', 'Cheese'];
  pending: any = [];

  getItem(deletedTask: any) {
    this.pending.push(deletedTask);

    this.service
      .getTask(reqMap)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe((resp: any) => {
        this.removePending(deletedTask);
      });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.removePending(deletedTask);
    }, 10000);
  }

  removePending(deletedTask: any) {
    if (this.pending.includes(deletedTask)) {
      this.pending = this.pending.filter((task) => task !== deletedTask);
    }
  }
}
```